# Receiving NOTIFY payloads via nPgSQL

Tags: c#, .net, database, npgsql

At present, I am using `NPGSQL` connector for connecting the PostgreSQL database with my application which is written in `VB.Net`.

I tried to `NOTIFY` the table changes for particular tables to the front-end using PostgreSQL's `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY` features. I got a positive outcome from that try. I successfully got notified from the back-end to the front end. For achieving that I tried out the following:

```
Public Sub test()

Dim conn = New NpgsqlConnection("Server=servername;port=portNo; _
           User Id=UID;pwd=PWD;DataBase=DB;")
conn.Open()

Dim command = New NpgsqlCommand("listen notifytest;", conn)
command.ExecuteNonQuery()


AddHandler conn.Notification, AddressOf NotificationSupportHelper

command = New NpgsqlCommand("notify notifytest;", conn)
command.ExecuteNonQuery()

End Sub

Private Sub NotificationSupportHelper(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                      ByVal e As NpgsqlNotificationEventArgs)

'Notified here.

End Sub
```

This is working fine, but, PostgreSQL has a brand new feature for notify where the notify can have a payload, like `NOTIFY test, 'Hello world'` (where Hello world is the payload, in other words, additional information).

I want to get that additional information in the Notification event handler `NotificationSupportHelper`. So in order to get that I just tried to access the members of `NpgsqlNotificationEventArgs`. But i got failed in that try, because it only contains PID and Condition as its members. So I decided to have a look at the [NPGQL documentation](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/api/index.html), from there, i got, there is no way to get additional information in NPGSQL vers 1.0. But they are providing an additional member for `NpgsqlNotificationEventArgs` called [AdditionalInformation](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/api/index.html) in their 2nd release (NPGSQL V 2.0). But it also currently under construction. this property will return String.Empty always(From the [docs](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/api/index.html)).

So i hope you people understood what i am trying to accomplish, I just needed to receive the `payload` in the front end when ever a `notification` got raised. Does anybody know how to achieve my requirement? Is there any other `connector` available rather than `NPGSQL` to handle `notification event` in the front end effectively, meaning getting the `payload` in the front end.?

Comment: I think you've already answered your question: From what you describe it sounds like nPgSQL doesn't support the notify payload yet. For most apps it's a convenience feature, you can just insert the data into an `UNLOGGED` table and have your program `SELECT` the data from the unlogged table when your program gets a `NOTIFY`.

Comment: Would you mind to add a feature request about that? You can do it in our tracker: http://pgfoundry.org/tracker/index.php?group_id=1000140&atid=593 Thanks in advance!

Comment: @FranciscoJunior Sure, I'll do it.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, Can you help me, what is wrong in code

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41727428/postgresql-notify-not-return-anything-when-insert-or-update?noredirect=1#comment70649944_41727428

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else has this question. An `AdditionalInformation` property is now available.

```
Private Sub NotificationSupportHelper(ByVal sender As Object,
                                  ByVal e As NpgsqlNotificationEventArgs)
    MsgBox(e.Condition & " " & e.AdditionalInformation)
End Sub
```